# Cannot change value of Select -Option

Tags: jquery, ajax, for-loop, drop-down-menu

This is my last resort,

I am trying to retrieve address data from a database, It has been retrieved using Ajax. I'm retrieving a value (number from 0-3) which I then need to preselect the value from the options. This happens multiple times as there is multiple addresses (as shown by a for loop)

For some unknown reason only the last Select is being selected (all others have not regular)

```
name = response.address_details[i].address_code;


$("[name="+ name +"]").find("option[value='2']").prop('selected',true);
```

Above is the code within the for loop that should get the current address code and select the option (static value=2 just for testing). Name retrieves each address code as the for loop continues

I have tried changing it to update based on class, and they all update, although when I try to match it with the name of the option (ie option name=183) it doesn't work.

Full code below:

```
      var table = document.getElementById('addressList')

    for (var i = 0; i < response.address_details.length; i++){
      var row = `
      <tr id="${response.address_details[i].address_code}">


      <td>${response.address_details[i].address}</td>
      <td>${response.address_details[i].address_code}</td>
      <td>${response.address_details[i].frequency}</td>

<td>
      <select name="${response.address_details[i].address_code}" class="address_code" id="183">
        <option value="0">Not regular</option>
        <option value="1">1</option>
        <option value="2">2</option>
        <option value="3">3</option>
      </select>
</td>

      </tr>`


      table.innerHTML += row
      name = response.address_details[i].address_code;


     $("[name="+ name +"]").find("option[value='2']").prop('selected',true);


    }
```

I have also tested using id instead of name and making the id variable, although it seems to be an issue with how this particular loop works and I cant seem to see the issue.

**In practice we should see each option be selected on 2 without using the class, and by identifying it using the unique name value** `response.address_details[i].address_code`

Comment: You can just write `$("selector").val(2)`

Comment: Where is the code that updates based on class?

Comment: Why don't you just put `<option value="2" selected>` in the HTML?